# ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 1000), found shape=(None, 30

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, tensorflow2.0

I need help with this error. I am attempting to train my LSTM model after training the neural network and fine-tuning

```
history = model.fit(XTrain ,yTrain, batch_size=250, epochs=100, validation_split=0.2,
         callbacks=[EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=10, restore_best_weights=True)])
```

The image below is the summary of my model:
[image]

**The Error**

```
Epoch 1/100
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-279-ebad9b5441a6> in <module>()
      1 history = model.fit(XTrain ,yTrain, batch_size=250, epochs=100, validation_split=0.2,
----> 2          callbacks=[EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=10, restore_best_weights=True)])

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in autograph_handler(*args, **kwargs)
   1145           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
   1146             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
-> 1147               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
   1148             else:
   1149               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1021, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1010, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1000, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 859, in train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/input_spec.py", line 264, in assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError(f'Input {input_index} of layer "{layer_name}" is '

    ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 1000), found shape=(None, 30)
```

Comment: What is wordIndex?

Comment: It's a parameter required for the Embedding function
```
This is a sample from the documentation: >>> model.add(tf.keras.layers.Embedding(1000, 64, input_length=10))
>>> # The model will take as input an integer matrix of size (batch,
>>> # input_length), and the largest integer (i.e. word index) in the input
>>> # should be no larger than 999 (vocabulary size).
>>> # Now model.output_shape is (None, 10, 64), where `None` is the batch
>>> # dimension.
```

Comment: What is xTrain? Not what the parameter is, but what's the data? If it's array-like, what's the shape? Some more of the surrounding code for context would help.

Comment: I've been able to fix it. Thanks for the help tho. I changed the shape of the data (xTrain) from 30 to 1000 to match the sequence layer